# how can I manipulate the layout of an itemrow of a recyclerView after a complete swipe of it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView with swipe functionality, but every time that I swipe an item, it is dismissed, and this is not what I am looking for. What I want is something like the WhatsApp swipe, that is, after a swipe, I can perform an action with that row without dismissing it. In this case, for example, I have a TextView with its visibility set to INVISIBLE, and after a complete swipe, I want it to become visible in the swiped row. Is there a way I can achieve this?

My AdapterClas:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

List <MyModel> list;
Context context;

public MyAdapter(List<MyModel> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemLista);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    MyModel myModel = list.get(position);

    holder.txt1.setText(String.valueOf(myModel.getPosition()));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView txt1;
    TextView txt2;


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txt1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_textView);
        txt2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_textView2);

        //I WANT TO MAKE THIS txt2 BECOME VISIBLE AFTER SWIPE



    }
}
```

The swipe functionality:

```
public void swipe () {
    ItemTouchHelper.Callback itemTouch = new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
        @Override
        public int getMovementFlags(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            int dragFlag = ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE;
            int swipeFlag = ItemTouchHelper.START|ItemTouchHelper.END;

            return makeMovementFlags(dragFlag,swipeFlag);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Swiped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

    new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouch).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

My RecyclerView layout row:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="6dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/row_textView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/row_textView2"/>
```

Comment: i think your swipe function is not right .

Comment: where did you use the swipe func.

Comment: OnCreate of MainActivity. What is wrong with it? Its working, i can swipe both sides and i get the Toast message in every swipe..but the row is dismissed after it, thats my problem.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your swipe section then will be ok.

```
@Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Swiped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```